# How to record Tango color camera video stream

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediarecorder, google-project-tango, textureview

I have been able to display the video from Tango color camera on a TextureView using TangoTextureCameraPreview. Now, I would like to record the video steam into .mp4 files. It is relatively easy with MediaRecorder and Camera2, but I am not sure how to do it with Tango. Is there a way to create a PersistentInputSurface from Tango that is accepted by MediaRecorder? If not, is the GLSurfaceView from TangoCameraPreview and MediaCodec the right direction to look into?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to use depth data or not. If not, Tango camera can act as a standard Android camera. If you don't want to write the code from scratch, you can check Media for Mobile API here: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile
It will work for Tango the same way it works for any other Android device.

Comment: Would you explain how to set tango camera as standard Android camera? The example from the m4m project uses camera api which is deprecated. Is there a way to use getIntExtra to get tango camera?
Thanks!